# Inserting time and certain value column into selected another rows table without pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've tried to insert certain values column (here time column and info column) and transfer it into another table (process table). But here, I have tried to use pivot but the right answer is not using pivoting table for this case. I've read any website though Google and ChatGPT for this solution and I've found two conditions for my table. So it should use case function in these. But I always fail when I tried to change each parameter on these. Also implement another command using with clause.

This is my query1:

```
INSERT INTO procestable (id,name, time_in, time_out,date,info1,info2)
SELECT
ID_karyawan,
nama_karyawan,
MAX(CASE WHEN row_number = 1 THEN jam END) as time_in,
MAX(CASE WHEN row_number = 2 THEN jam END) as time_out,
tanggal,
MAX(CASE WHEN row_number = 1 THEN jam END) as info1,
MAX(CASE WHEN row_number = 2 THEN jam END) as info2    
FROM (
SELECT
ID_karyawan,
nama_karyawan,
jam,
tanggal,
arah,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_karyawan,nama_karyawan,jam,tanggal,arah ORDER BY jam,arah) 
as row_number
FROM table1
) AS table1
GROUP BY ID_karyawan;
```

This table1:

```
ID_karyawan  nama_karyawan  jam      tanggal    arah
1             ridho     07:44:45    2023-07-20  masuk
1             ridho     17:04:46    2023-07-20  keluar
3             Yuwono    17:24:47    2023-07-20  keluar
3             Yuwono    06:58:41    2023-07-20  masuk
4             Ety       07:51:48    2023-07-20  masuk
4             Ety       17:04:07    2023-07-20  keluar
5             Joseph    17:03:48    2023-07-20  keluar
5             Joseph    07:40:31    2023-07-20  masuk
1             ridho     07:44:45    2023-07-21  masuk
1             ridho     17:04:46    2023-07-21  keluar
3             Yuwono    17:24:47    2023-07-21  keluar
3             Yuwono    06:58:41    2023-07-21  masuk
4             Ety       07:51:48    2023-07-21  masuk
4             Ety       17:04:07    2023-07-21  keluar
5             Joseph    17:03:48    2023-07-21  keluar
5             Joseph    07:40:31    2023-07-21  masuk
1             ridho     07:44:45    2023-07-22  masuk
1             ridho     17:04:46    2023-07-22  keluar
3             Yuwono    17:24:47    2023-07-22  keluar
3             Yuwono    06:58:41    2023-07-22  masuk
4             Ety       07:51:48    2023-07-22  masuk
4             Ety       17:04:07    2023-07-22  keluar
5             Joseph    17:03:48    2023-07-22  keluar
5             Joseph    07:40:31    2023-07-22  masuk
```

Expected insert into another table(proces table):

```
id  name    time_in     time_out       date    info1   info2
1   ridho   07:44:45    17:04:46    2023-07-20  masuk   keluar
3   Yuwono  06:58:41    17:24:47    2023-07-20  masuk   keluar
4   Ety     07:51:48    17:04:07    2023-07-20  masuk   keluar
5   Joseph  07:40:31    17:03:48    2023-07-20  masuk   keluar
1   ridho   07:44:45    17:04:46    2023-07-21  masuk   keluar
2   Yuwono  06:58:41    17:24:41    2023-07-21  masuk   keluar
3   Ety     07:51:48    17:04:07    2023-07-21  masuk   keluar
4   Joseph  07:40:31    17:03:48    2023-07-21  masuk   keluar
1   ridho   07:44:45    17:04:46    2023-07-22  masuk   keluar
2   Yuwono  06:58:41    17:24:41    2023-07-22  masuk   keluar
3   Ety     07:51:48    17:04:07    2023-07-22  masuk   keluar
4   Joseph  07:40:31    17:03:48    2023-07-22  masuk   keluar
```

Someone who know this, I've get stuck and I don't know which website/true query are. so far I've tried and I don't get the right query, but still trying. Also any StackOverflow post almost showing using pivoting table for transposing table. But in this case is different. Any suggestion about this.

Comment: ok,ive edited for the title...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the concepts about the row_number partition order to get the number of rows you are referencing in the case expression.

The following query will produce the expected data:

```sql
INSERT INTO procestable (id,name, time_in, time_out,date,info1,info2)
SELECT ID_karyawan
     , nama_karyawan
     , MAX(CASE WHEN row_number = 1 THEN jam END) as time_in
     , MAX(CASE WHEN row_number = 2 THEN jam END) as time_out
     , tanggal
     , MAX(CASE WHEN row_number = 1 THEN arah END) as info1
     , MAX(CASE WHEN row_number = 2 THEN arah END) as info2
  FROM (SELECT ID_karyawan
             , nama_karyawan
             , jam
             , tanggal
             , arah
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_karyawan
                                          , nama_karyawan
                                          , tanggal
                                      ORDER BY jam
                                          ,arah
                                 ) as row_number
          FROM table1
       ) AS table1
 GROUP BY ID_karyawan
     , nama_karyawan
     , tanggal
 order by tanggal
     , ID_karyawan;
```

Next time, try to run the internal subquery first to confirm that it is producing the data you are expecting to parse with the `CASE` expression, it should be very helpful.